# Does UIDocumentInteractionViewController Supports Video?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I tried to know whether UIDocumentInteractionViewController supports video but i am unable to get it

Comment: Please add more details along with your tried code so far.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It supports video upload.

You can pass 'Uniform Type Identifiers' when initialising 'UIDocumentPickerViewController'

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: .import)
```

Another example for only PDFs

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.composite-content"], in: .import)
```

You can check the allowed types on apple site.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1

Comment: Yes, we can upload but I am unable to play video in UIDocumentInteractionViewController

Comment: Do you want to check it before uploading? Like preview or editing functionality?